# How can I correctly expand the result of \prop_item:Nn to work with my own \DoSomething function?

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

OK, here is the thing. I want to store property-value pairs and then later use this as a lookup table to feed the value into another function. This is what I came up with and I don't know how to fix the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Create a new sequence.
\prop_clear_new:N {\MyLookupTable}

\prop_put:Nnn {\MyLookupTable} {key1} {intermediate1}
\prop_put:Nnn {\MyLookupTable} {key2} {intermediate2}


\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF {xn}
\NewDocumentCommand{\DoSomething}{m}{%
    \str_case:xnF {\str_fold_case:n{#1}}
    {
        {intermediate1} {Result~1}
        {intermediate2} {Result~2}
    }
{Unknown~intermediate}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
Test1: \ExplSyntaxOn\prop_if_in:NnTF {\MyLookupTable} {key1} {\DoSomething{\prop_item:Nn {\IconNameToUnicodeList} {key1}}} {key1~not~in~list}\ExplSyntaxOff ~However: \DoSomething{intermediate1}

Test2: \ExplSyntaxOn\prop_if_in:NnTF {\MyLookupTable} {key1} {key1~found} {key1~not~in~list}\ExplSyntaxOff ~And: \DoSomething{intermediate1}

Final: \ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_get:NnNTF {\MyLookupTable} {key1} {\answer} {TRUE: \DoSomething{\answer}} {FALSE}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I tried a `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \DoSomething:m {V}` but LaTeX didn't like it and I am still not very familiar with the LaTeX3 structure.

Comment: N arguments should always be a single token not a brace group as you have here, also note you only need to load expl3 and xparse in old formats expl3 has been loaded by default for some time and xparse since last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the proper recommended naming scheme. You have a wrong name in he code, by the way.

Note that `x`-expansion is not expandable, but there is `\str_case_e:nnF` that does “expandable expansion”.

Also, you need to `e`-expand the argument passed to `\DoSomething`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Create a new sequence.
\prop_clear_new:N \l_tobibs_lookup_prop

\prop_put:Nnn \l_tobibs_lookup_prop {key1} {intermediate1}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_tobibs_lookup_prop {key2} {intermediate2}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\DoSomething}{m}
  {
    \tobibs_dosomething:e { #1 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \tobibs_dosomething:n
  {
    \str_case_e:nnF {\str_foldcase:n{#1}}
      {
        {intermediate1} {Result~1}
        {intermediate2} {Result~2}
      }
      {Unknown~intermediate}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobibs_dosomething:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test1:
 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_if_in:NnTF \l_tobibs_lookup_prop {key1}
  {\DoSomething{\prop_item:Nn \l_tobibs_lookup_prop {key1}}}
  {key1~not~in~list}
\ExplSyntaxOff

However: \DoSomething{intermediate1}

\bigskip

Test2:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_if_in:NnTF \l_tobibs_lookup_prop {key1}
  {key1~found}
  {key1~not~in~list}
\ExplSyntaxOff 

And: \DoSomething{intermediate1}

\bigskip

Final:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_get:NnNTF \l_tobibs_lookup_prop {key1} \answer {TRUE: \DoSomething{\answer}} {FALSE}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid bracing `N` arguments (although it's not really a problem).

Note: `\str_fold_case:n` should be `\str_foldcase:n` (the latter used to be the official name, but it was renamed for consistency with other names).

Comment: Thank you @egreg, my local version of LaTeX seems to be to old to directly make use of your code, as it yields errors, especially without ```xparse``` and ```expl3```, but I am on the way to update it and then understand the answer, thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of capsulating ```\DoSomething``` and what is the purpose of generating the variant through ```\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobibs_dosomething:n { e }``` instead of directly defining it that way?

Comment: @TobiBS That's the recommended way: if the document command must do complex work, its definition should just pass the arguments to an internal function. Anyway, how would you do it?

Comment: Well as I cannot test it on my machine right now, I can just describe what I was thinking should be possible: Directly say ```\cs_new:Ne \tobibs_dosomething:e``` and would look if there is a way to directly put the code into ```\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\DoSomething}{m}```

Comment: @TobiBS No, `\cs_new:Nn` only manages `N` and `n` argument types. To have `e` you *must* generate a variant.

Comment: In the latest documantation, I can only find `\str_foldcase:n` but not `\str_fold_case:n`.

Comment: @L.J.R. I took it from the OP's code and didn't check. Fixed.